# Points are being incorrectly counted

Tags: javascript, html, css, game-physics

I have another question about game creation, that I already reached out for.

As I continued developing the [game](https://codepen.io/iph03nix/pen/oVZjag) and tried to implement point counter I have encountered another issue.

It seems that sometimes the points are being counter instead of +1 to +2 or even +3.
I am suspecting incorrect placement of the code-part `expo += 1` as it would (probably) get looped 2 (or multiple) times instead of once, but frankly, I am not sure.

The code can be found [here](https://codepen.io/iph03nix/pen/wOdmbJ) or below:

```js
var LEVELS = [
  ["                                  x  x",
   "                                  xx x",
   "                      xxx         x  x",
   "                     xx!xx        x ox",
   "                     x!!!x        x xx",
   "                     xx!xx        x  x",
   "  x                   xvx         x  x",
   "  x                               xx x",
   "  x                               x  x",
   "  x                               x  x",
   "  x                               x xx",
   "  x                                  x",
   "  x @                xxxxx     o     x",
   "  xxxxxx     xxxxxxxxx   xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
   "       x     x                        ",
   "       x!!!!!x                        ",
   "       x!!!!!x                        ",
   "       xxxxxxx                        ",
   "                                      "],
 ];

var life = 3;
var expo = 0;
document.getElementById("life").innerHTML = ("Lives left: " + life);
document.getElementById("expo").innerHTML = ("Points: " + expo);

function Vector(x, y) {
 this.x = x; this.y = y;
}

Vector.prototype.plus = function(other) {
 return new Vector(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
};

Vector.prototype.times = function(scale) {
 return new Vector(this.x * scale, this.y * scale);
};

// Note: uppercase words are used that means constructor are values
var actorchars =  {
 "@": Player,
 "o": Coin,
 "=": Lava,
  "|": Lava,
 "v": Lava,
 "#": Lava
};

function Player(pos) {
 this.pos = pos.plus(new Vector(0, -.5));
 this.size = new Vector(.5, 1);
 this.speed = new Vector(0, 0);
}
Player.prototype.type = "player";

function Lava(pos, ch) {
 this.pos = pos;
 this.size = new Vector(1, 1);
 if (ch === "=")
  this.speed = new Vector(2, 0);
 else if (ch === '|')
  this.speed = new Vector(0, 2);
 else if (ch === 'v'){
  this.speed = new Vector(0, 5); // new Vector(0, 3);   
  this.repeatPos = pos;
  } else if (ch === '#'){
   this.speed = new Vector(0, 10);
 }
}
Lava.prototype.type = "lava"
//Lava.prototype.type = "Lava";

function Coin(pos) {
 this.basePos = this.pos = pos;
 this.size = new Vector(.6, .6);
 // take a look back
 this.wobble = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
}
Coin.prototype.type = "coin";

Level.prototype.isFinished = function() {
  return this.status !== null && this.finishDelay < 0;
};

function Level(plan) {
 this.width = plan[0].length;
 this.height = plan.length;
 this.grid = [];
 this.actors = [];
 
 for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
  var line = plan[y],  gridLine = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
   var ch = line[x], fieldType = null;
   var Actor = actorchars[ch];
   if (Actor)
    this.actors.push(new Actor(new Vector(x, y), ch));
   else if (ch === "x")
    fieldType = "wall";
   else if (ch === "!")
    fieldType = "lava";
   else if (ch === "|")
    fieldType = "lava";
   else if (ch === "=")
    fieldType = "lava";
      else if (ch === "#")
    fieldType = "lava";  
   else if (ch === "v"){
    fieldType = "lava";
    console.log(fieldType);
   }
   gridLine.push(fieldType);
  }
  this.grid.push(gridLine);
 }
 this.player = this.actors.filter(function(actor) {
  return actor.type === "player";
 })[0]; 
 this.status = this.finishDelay = null;
}

function element(name, className) {
 var elem = document.createElement(name);
 if(className) elem.className = className;
 return elem;
}

function DOMDisplay(parent, level) {
 this.wrap = parent.appendChild(element("div", "game"));
 this.level = level;
 
 this.wrap.appendChild(this.drawBackground());
 this.actorLayer = null;
 this.drawFrame();
}


var scale = 15;


DOMDisplay.prototype.drawBackground = function() {
 var table = element("table", "background");
 table.style.width = this.level.width * scale + "px";
 table.style.height = this.level.height * scale + "px";
 this.level.grid.forEach(function(row) {
  var rowElement = table.appendChild(element("tr"));
  rowElement.style.height = scale + "px";
  row.forEach(function(type) {
   rowElement.appendChild(element("td", type));
  });
 });
 return table;
};

DOMDisplay.prototype.drawActors = function() {
 var wrap = element("div");
 this.level.actors.forEach(function(actor) {
  var rect = wrap.appendChild(element("div", "actor " + actor.type));
  rect.style.width = actor.size.x * scale + "px";
  rect.style.height = actor.size.y * scale + "px";
  rect.style.left = actor.pos.x * scale + "px";
  rect.style.top = actor.pos.y * scale + "px";
 });
 return wrap;
};

DOMDisplay.prototype.drawFrame = function() {
 if (this.actorLayer)
  this.wrap.removeChild(this.actorLayer);
 this.actorLayer = this.wrap.appendChild(this.drawActors());
 this.wrap.className = "game " + (this.level.status || "");
 this.scrollPlayerIntoView();
};


// clear it later
DOMDisplay.prototype.scrollPlayerIntoView = function() {
  var width = this.wrap.clientWidth;
  var height = this.wrap.clientHeight;
  var margin = width / 3;

  // The viewport
  var left = this.wrap.scrollLeft, right = left + width;
  var top = this.wrap.scrollTop, bottom = top + height;

  var player = this.level.player;
  var center = player.pos.plus(player.size.times(0.5))
                 .times(scale);

  if (center.x < left + margin)
    this.wrap.scrollLeft = center.x - margin;
  else if (center.x > right - margin)
    this.wrap.scrollLeft = center.x + margin - width;
  if (center.y < top + margin)
    this.wrap.scrollTop = center.y - margin;
  else if (center.y > bottom - margin)
    this.wrap.scrollTop = center.y + margin - height;
};

DOMDisplay.prototype.clear = function() {
 this.wrap.parentNode.removeChild(this.wrap);
};

Level.prototype.obstacleAt = function(pos, size) {
  var xStart = Math.floor(pos.x);
  var xEnd = Math.ceil(pos.x + size.x);
  var yStart = Math.floor(pos.y);
  var yEnd = Math.ceil(pos.y + size.y);

  if (xStart < 0 || xEnd > this.width || yStart < 0)
    return "wall";
  if (yEnd > this.height)
    return "lava";
  for (var y = yStart; y < yEnd; y++) {
    for (var x = xStart; x < xEnd; x++) {
      var fieldType = this.grid[y][x];
      if (fieldType) return fieldType;
    }
  }
};

Level.prototype.actorAt = function(actor) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.actors.length; i++) {
    var other = this.actors[i];
    if (other != actor &&
        actor.pos.x + actor.size.x > other.pos.x &&
        actor.pos.x < other.pos.x + other.size.x &&
        actor.pos.y + actor.size.y > other.pos.y &&
        actor.pos.y < other.pos.y + other.size.y)
      return other;
  }
};

var maxStep = 0.05;

Level.prototype.animate = function(step, keys) {
  if (this.status !== null)
    this.finishDelay -= step;

  while (step > 0) {
    var thisStep = Math.min(step, maxStep);
    this.actors.forEach(function(actor) {
      actor.act(thisStep, this, keys);
    }, this);
    step -= thisStep;
  }
};


Lava.prototype.act = function(step, level) {
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(this.speed.times(step));
  if (!level.obstacleAt(newPos, this.size))
    this.pos = newPos;
  else if (this.repeatPos)
    this.pos = this.repeatPos;
  else
    this.speed = this.speed.times(-1);
};

var wobbleSpeed = 8, wobbleDist = 0.07;

Coin.prototype.act = function(step) {
  this.wobble += step * wobbleSpeed;
  var wobblePos = Math.sin(this.wobble) * wobbleDist;
  this.pos = this.basePos.plus(new Vector(0, wobblePos));
};


var playerXSpeed = 10;

Player.prototype.moveX = function(step, level, keys) {
  this.speed.x = 0;
  if (keys.left) this.speed.x -= playerXSpeed;
  if (keys.right) this.speed.x += playerXSpeed;

  var motion = new Vector(this.speed.x * step, 0);
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(motion);
  var obstacle = level.obstacleAt(newPos, this.size);
  if (obstacle)
    level.playerTouched(obstacle);
  else
    this.pos = newPos;
};

var gravity = 30;
var jumpSpeed = 17;

Player.prototype.moveY = function(step, level, keys) {
  this.speed.y += step * gravity;
  var motion = new Vector(0, this.speed.y * step);
  var newPos = this.pos.plus(motion);
  var obstacle = level.obstacleAt(newPos, this.size);
  if (obstacle) {
    level.playerTouched(obstacle);
    if (keys.up && this.speed.y > 0)
      this.speed.y = -jumpSpeed;
    else
      this.speed.y = 0;
  } else {
    this.pos = newPos;
  }
};

Player.prototype.act = function(step, level, keys) {
  this.moveX(step, level, keys);
  this.moveY(step, level, keys);

  var otherActor = level.actorAt(this);
  if (otherActor)
    level.playerTouched(otherActor.type, otherActor);

  // Losing animation
  if (level.status == "lost") {
    this.pos.y += step;
    this.size.y -= step;
  }
};

Level.prototype.playerTouched = function(type, actor) {
  //if (type == "lava" || type == "Lava" && this.status === null) { //DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK, FIND OUT WHY MASS DAMAGE
  if (type == "lava" && this.status === null) {
    this.status = "lost";
   life -= 1;
   console.log(life);
    expo = 0;
    document.getElementById("expo").innerHTML = ("Points: " + expo);
   document.getElementById("life").innerHTML = ("Lives left: " + life);
   if(life < 0) { 
  sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "true");
  document.location.reload();
   }
    this.finishDelay = 1;
  } else if (type == "coin") {
    this.actors = this.actors.filter(function(other) {
      return other != actor;
    });
    if (!this.actors.some(function(actor) {
      console.log("coin picked up")
      expo += 1;
    document.getElementById("expo").innerHTML = ("Points: " + expo);
      return actor.type == "coin";
    })) {
   life += 1;
   document.getElementById("life").innerHTML = ("Lives left: " + life);
      this.status = "won";
      this.finishDelay = 1;
    }
  }
};

var arrowCodes = {37: "left", 38: "up", 39: "right"};

function trackKeys(codes) {
  var pressed = Object.create(null);
  function handler(event) {
    if (codes.hasOwnProperty(event.keyCode)) {
      var down = event.type == "keydown";
      pressed[codes[event.keyCode]] = down;
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  addEventListener("keydown", handler);
  addEventListener("keyup", handler);
  return pressed;
}

function runAnimation(frameFunc) {
  var lastTime = null;
  function frame(time) {
    var stop = false;
    if (lastTime !== null) {
      var timeStep = Math.min(time - lastTime, 100) / 1000;
      stop = frameFunc(timeStep) === false;
    }
    lastTime = time;
    if (!stop)
      requestAnimationFrame(frame);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}

var arrows = trackKeys(arrowCodes);

function runLevel(level, Display, andThen) {
  var display = new Display(document.body, level);
  runAnimation(function(step) {
    level.animate(step, arrows);
    display.drawFrame(step);
    if (level.isFinished()) {
      display.clear();
      if (andThen)
        andThen(level.status);
      return false;
    }
  });
}


var lives = function() {
 ctx.font = "20px Courier";
 ctx.fontFamily = "monospace";
 ctx.fillStyle = "#666";
 ctx.textAlign = "left";
 ctx.textBaseline = "top";
 ctx.fillText("Lives left: " + life, 10, 10);
};


function runGame(plans, Display) {
  function startLevel(n) {
    runLevel(new Level(plans[n]), Display, function(status) {
      if (status == "lost") {
        startLevel(n);       
   } else if (n < plans.length - 1)
        startLevel(n + 1);
      else
        alert("You win!");
    });
  }
  startLevel(0);
}

function restart() {
  sessionStorage.setItem("reloading", "true");
  document.location.reload();
}

runGame(LEVELS, DOMDisplay);
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}

h2 {
  color: #666;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
}

.background {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.background td {
  padding: 0;
}

.lava, .actor {
  background: #e55;
}

.wall {
  background: #444;
  border: solid 3px #333;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.actor {
  position: absolute;
}

.coin {
  background: #e2e838;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.player {
  background: #335699;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.lost .player {
  background: #a04040;
}

.won .player {
  background: green;
}

.game {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#life, #expo {
  font = 20px;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #666;
  text-align: left;
  baseline: top;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input {
  margin-left: 30px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>game</title>  
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Simple JavaScript Game</h2>
  <div id="life"></div>
  <div id="expo"></div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" onclick="restart()" value="Restart"/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have already tried some options and quite interesting, was that if I removed all "lava sources" as variants or/and all collisions of those, the counter would work as it should.

Another level, that might get some ideas about my findings, found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3f9byd10/3/).

I will really appreciate any help, Thanks

EDIT::
I would like to mess with the existing code as minimal as possible, if not, I will have to scrap the code and redo most of it (at least that's the only option I saw).

Comment: Strangely enough, I somehow accidentally fixed the problem. Still trying to figure it out how I did it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it seems that what fixed my issue was incorrect placement of the following sentences:

`expo += 1;
document.getElementById("expo").innerHTML = ("Points: " + expo);`

The placement of code before:

```
else if (type == "coin") {
  this.actors = this.actors.filter(function(other) {
  return other != actor;
});
if (!this.actors.some(function(actor) {
  console.log("coin picked up")
  expo += 1;
  document.getElementById("expo").innerHTML = ("Points: " + expo);
  return actor.type == "coin";
})) {
  life += 1;
  document.getElementById("life").innerHTML = ("Lives left: " + life);
  this.status = "won";
  this.finishDelay = 1;
}
```

The correct placement of the code:

```
else if (type == "coin") {
  expo += 1;
  document.getElementById("expo").innerHTML = ("Points: " + expo);
  this.actors = this.actors.filter(function(other) {
  return other != actor;
});
if (!this.actors.some(function(actor) {
  console.log("coin picked up")
  return actor.type == "coin";
})) {
  life += 1;
  document.getElementById("life").innerHTML = ("Lives left: " + life);
  this.status = "won";
  this.finishDelay = 1;
}
```